# Question about inner product axiom

Tags: inner-products

When reading about the inner product for complex vector spaces, some sources say that the inner product must satisfy $\langle c\vec{u}, \vec{v}\rangle = \bar{c}\langle \vec{u}, \vec{v} \rangle $ and $\langle \vec{u}, c\vec{v}\rangle = c\langle \vec{u}, \vec{v} \rangle $ where other sources say that  $\langle \vec{u}, c\vec{v}\rangle = \bar{c}\langle \vec{u}, \vec{v} \rangle $ and $\langle c\vec{u}, \vec{v}\rangle = c\langle \vec{u}, \vec{v} \rangle $. Is there a reason to use one convention over another? Is one more 'common'?

Source for the first version:

[http://www.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ehking/Hermitian.pdf)

Source for the second version

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html

Comment: Until this post  I've never seen an inner product being conjugate linear in the first coordinate, always in the second.

Comment: The conjugate-linear in the first argument is more common in physics. I also prefer it that way since you can for instance write an inner product as $u^\dagger v$ and a projection operator as $vv^\dagger$ for column vectors, which go hand-in-hand in many derivations and calculations.

Comment: Ah it being more common in physics makes sense, thank you!